# Django REST how to render chosen fields in forms

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am new to Django REST, pls help, how to render only some fields from the form, so now I am getting all fields and related tables, however i need to show just some fields

View:

```
class ProFormList(APIView):
renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
template_name = "accounts/page_user_profile.html"



def get(self, request, id):
    account = get_object_or_404(Account, id=id)
    serializer = AccountSerializer(account)
    return Response({'serializer': serializer, 'account':account})


def post(self, request, id):
    account = get_object_or_404(Account, id=id)
    serializer = AccountSerializer(account, data=request.data)
    if not serializer.is_valid():
        return Response({'serializer': serializer, 'account':account})
    serializer.save()
    return redirect('accounts:profile', id=account.id)
```

my Html:

```
 <div class="tab-pane " id="tab_1_2">
    <form role="form" action="{% url 'accounts:proform' id=account.id %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% render_form serializer %}
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="margiv-top-10">
                                                                                    <button type="submit" class="btn green"> Save Changes </button>
   <button type="" class="btn default"> Cancel </button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use Meta: fields in your serializer

Answer (score 0):

```
class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    first_name = serializers.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        style={'placeholder': 'first name'}
    )
    last_name = serializers.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        style={'placeholder': 'last name'}
    )
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.